# How to output static contents using gwt-gradle?

Tags: java, gwt, gradle, static-content

I've built an web-based application using GWT, which does not require any XHR calls. Since every contents are static, the whole application should be servable without servlets, for example deploying static files under working nginx directory, etc.

By using `war` command of gwt-gradle-plugin, you can generate a .war file. Mentioned above, I want static files. Is it possible? How can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude everything you don't need from the generated war file, like this :

```
war {
    exclude('**/deploy/**')
    exclude('**/tests/**')
    rootSpec.exclude("**/*.class")
    rootSpec.exclude("**/*.jar")
}
```